# How can I make my android app interact with Flask server on raspberry pi 3?

Tags: android, python, flask, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to follow the MattRichardson's tutorial on "Serving Raspberry Pi with Flask" (http://mattrichardson.com/Raspberry-Pi-Flask/). Here is the code I got from the tutorial mentioned on this site:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# Create a dictionary called pins to store the pin number, name, and pin state:
pins = {
   24 : {'name' : 'coffee maker', 'state' : GPIO.LOW},
   25 : {'name' : 'lamp', 'state' : GPIO.LOW}
   }

# Set each pin as an output and make it low:
for pin in pins:
   GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)
   GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)

@app.route("/")
def main():
   # For each pin, read the pin state and store it in the pins dictionary:
   for pin in pins:
      pins[pin]['state'] = GPIO.input(pin)
   # Put the pin dictionary into the template data dictionary:
   templateData = {
      'pins' : pins
      }
   # Pass the template data into the template main.html and return it to the user
   return render_template('main.html', **templateData)

# The function below is executed when someone requests a URL with the pin number and action in it:
@app.route("/<changePin>/<action>")
def action(changePin, action):
   # Convert the pin from the URL into an integer:
   changePin = int(changePin)
   # Get the device name for the pin being changed:
   deviceName = pins[changePin]['name']
   # If the action part of the URL is "on," execute the code indented below:
   if action == "on":
      # Set the pin high:
      GPIO.output(changePin, GPIO.HIGH)
      # Save the status message to be passed into the template:
      message = "Turned " + deviceName + " on."
   if action == "off":
      GPIO.output(changePin, GPIO.LOW)
      message = "Turned " + deviceName + " off."
   if action == "toggle":
      # Read the pin and set it to whatever it isn't (that is, toggle it):
      GPIO.output(changePin, not GPIO.input(changePin))
      message = "Toggled " + deviceName + "."

   # For each pin, read the pin state and store it in the pins dictionary:
   for pin in pins:
      pins[pin]['state'] = GPIO.input(pin)

   # Along with the pin dictionary, put the message into the template data dictionary:
   templateData = {
      'message' : message,
      'pins' : pins
   }

   return render_template('main.html', **templateData)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

and for the main.htm file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
   <title>Current Status</title>
</head>

<body>
   <h1>Device Listing and Status</h1>

   {% for pin in pins %}
   <p>The {{ pins[pin].name }}
   {% if pins[pin].state == true %}
      is currently on (<a href="/{{pin}}/off">turn off</a>)
   {% else %}
      is currently off (<a href="/{{pin}}/on">turn on</a>)
   {% endif %}
   </p>
   {% endfor %}

   {% if message %}
   <h2>{{ message }}</h2>
   {% endif %}

</body>
</html>
```

Wjat the above code does is, it lets the user access the pi's web server and control the GPIO pins, i.e. to turn them on or off.

At the time being, I have a raspberry pi serving the above html file for my web browser to access. However, I want to achieve the same thing using a simple android app, i.e. a simple toggle button which in some way turns the pins on or off.

Here's my android app code. All this app has a simple button at the center of the screen, just for the sake of letting me control the pins.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Switch"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and the java code:

```
package com.example.testapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: I don't see in your android code where you're listening or sending to HTTP posts to communicate with the flask server.

Comment: The android app code is nothing more than a sample app with just a button at the center. But I don't know how to make it interact with the server? Oh! I think I got a pointer through your comment: "Listening or sending to HTTP post".... Thanks.

Comment: I may suggest looking into Retrofit if your tutorial doesn't suggest how to send/receive an HTTP post request. https://medium.com/@prakash_pun/retrofit-a-simple-android-tutorial-48437e4e5a23

Comment: Thanks mattsap.. Your suggestion really saved my day :) and I am well on my way to controlling the raspberry pi from android app.